# Return a string and int

Tags: java

How do i return a string and an integer? say i wanted to return 
students name which is an string and their mark which is an integer.

I cant do mark=mark+element+(element2+name); that creates an incompatible type.

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion in this type of situation is to create a new class that holds this information. Name it for example `StudentMark`.

```
class StudentMark {
  private final String name;
  private final int mark;

  public StudentMark(String name, int mark) {
     this.name = name;
     this.mark = mark;
  }
  public String getName() { return name; }
  public int getMark() { return mark; }
}
```

Then in your method that has both the name and mark where you want to return, just do like so.

```
return new StudentMark("Samuel", 3.2);
```

Here you can also add any other interesting methods that you might need.

Comment: @F.Dot alright, updated with an example on how to use such a class.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class Student and return a student

```
class Student{
  private String name;
  private int mark;
  //assessor+ contructors

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to define a class for it. the class should have two attributes: a string and an int

Comment: done that, i have a subclass and a super class. this new class takes vector elements of those clases

Comment: i don't understand you comment. see the answer of Jigar Joshi, that's also pretty much what I had in mind

Answer (score 0):

Define a class that contains both values and return an object of that class.

Answer (score 0):

create A class with priavte variables for name and marks. and override toString() method.

```
   public class Student{
    private int marks;
    private String name;
    //provde setters and getters for marks and name

    public String toString(){
return getName()+getMarks();
  }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Student` class, you can have a method:

```
 public String printNameAndGrade() {
    return "Name: " + this.getName() + "\n " + "Grade: " +  this.getGrade();
}
```

and then call it with a Student object reference:

```
Student st1 = new Student("Gabe Logan", 97);
System.out.println(st1.printNameAndGrade()); //use `println` method to display it.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a two element Array or List and put the values in there. Unfortunately this looses all type Information.

You can use a Map which keeps the type information, but might be confusing because you would expect an arbitrary number of entries.

The cleanest option is to create a simple class with the two elements.